# ssh using python(without paramiko and fabric)

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have a requirement to write a python script to do a ssh login from one server to the other. Unfortunately these servers do not have any internet connection and i am not able to download packages. 
I have written the below code using python sub process but once the ssh command is executed stdin.write dose not input the password.
I have tried p.communicate also but to no avail.
Please help me on this script to ssh without using paramiko or fabric.

```
cmd = "ssh root@17.10.14.243"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout =  subprocess.PIPE, stderr =  subprocess.PIPE, bufsize = 1,shell = True)
p.stdin.write("Pass")
```

Comment: Can you download `fabric` with dependencies on another computer and install it on your servers? I had the same problem in my job and solved it that way.

Comment: i can try it out for sure. How would i install fabric on linux(red hat) with downloaded files. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I hope that's not your real password in the question!

`ssh` won't read passwords from `stdin`, so using `p.communicate` or various writes sadly won't work.

If it's always these two machines, you could ensure that they both have ssh identities and then make an `authorized_keys` file. If you don't set a password when creating an ssh identity with `ssh-keygen`, and that key is in another user@host's `authorized_keys` file, then you'll be let in without a password:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
ssh-copy-id user@other-host
```

If `ssh-copy-id` doesn't exist on your system, then you want to put the contents of `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into the other host's `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (which can have multiple entries)

There is also `ssh-askpass`, if that's installed on your system. Setting the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable to the name of a script will run that script to get the password to use, if ssh is run without an attached terminal. So if `/path/to/myscript` prints out `mypassword`, then `export SSH_ASKPASS=/path/to/myscript` will use `mypassword` when there's no terminal available.

Both options have their security concerns, so it depends on the environment you have and what you're most worried about.

Comment: thanks for your response. Sadly i dont have SSH_ASKPASS installed. And once there is a ssh connection initiated and password entered a corresponding log would be generated. This log is what i have to validate. Hence entering the password is mandatory. And also the IP's would vary depending on the servers being used.

Comment: Logins with the ssh identity trusts are still logged, if that's any use.